# Rounding up arithmetic expression

Tags: c#

```
itog = first/second/third;
```

All variables are int.

How I can round up boxTotal without casting to double all vars?

Comment: If you're trying to do division then you really shouldn't be using integers at all anway

Comment: Your question seems little bit unclear to me. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) includes your values and expected result at least?

Answer (score 2):

Typical language-independent implementation for two numbers is `(a+(b-1))/b`, where `a` and `b` are integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it when all of them are integers. At least one of them has to be double or float. To round to the nearest integer you can use `Math.Ceiling(value)` but you have to cast what you put in the brackets as decimal and the result as int.
Example :

```
int result = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)yourExpression);
```

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be yourExpression. Thank you for that @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to cast all to double then

```
itlog = (int)Math.Ceiling(first/(double)second/third);
```

would probably work, although I haven't tested it. You will need to cast at least one to double other wise the division will be wrong.

Comment: thanks, edited as suggested.  As I said, haven't run the code.  For some reason thought operations would be from right to left which now I think about it is totally wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from gudok's answer, you could use this:

```
itog = (first/second +(third - 1)) / third;
```